# Redirect on session timeout tomcat 7

Tags: gwt, tomcat, jaas

I would like to redirect users back a login page immediately when a session has timed out, without a user having to send a request to the server.
1. Is there a configuration tag that could be put in the web.xml or context.xml to handle this? Something like /loginPage
2. If not, is there a reason why tomcat does have this? What contract does it break?
3. Is there a way to accomplish this using tomcat, jaas, and gwt?

I have tried using an HttpSessionListener, but that does not work since you cannot (maybe I don't know how) send a redirect to the user from a Session object. I have tried using filters, but filters are only called when there is a request made.

I am fairly new to user authentication and web stuff, so hopefully I have framed the questions correctly and have not abused the terminology. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added my initial unsuccessful attempts to solve this problem. I am not doubting that my question deserved to be down voted, but with out an explanation as to why, the down vote does not help at all. Please let me know if there is anything else that I can add to help you help me.

Comment: It is standard web behaviour. Server cannot communicate to Client ( browser ). It is always the browser that has to initiate and server can only respond.

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically, server is not able to initiate the communication when using standard HTTP protocol. You may hack this by using some techniques of long polling or server push. If you are using GWT, I would suggest looking into [Errai](http://www.jboss.org/errai) framework. It is a lot of overhead in learning new things, but then you will be able to notify users from the server side using the Errai bus.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hacky approach. This relies on the failure of the first app async callback fired on a user whose session is closed

On session time out on server always return exception for all async calls for the user. Which you can catch in failure block of the GWT async callback (all async callback in your app) and then redirect the app from GWT code using  Window and Navigator class ( com.google.gwt.user.client package)